# Why do prototype scope is used with Stateful bean?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, javabeans

Spring docs -
As a rule of thumb, you should use the prototype scope for all beans that are stateful, while the singleton scope should be used for stateless beans.

So a stateful bean is necessary when you have to maintain some state/data consistently across a context. Say banking app. You would expect your object to be in sync throughout the various operations(Deposit,withdraw,etc).

So in a singleton scope, you get the same thing - Object consistency across the context.

So why does the javadoc state the oppposite?

Help!! :)

Comment: If you have a singleton stateful bean the state will be overwriten every time it's accessed, rendering it useless

Comment: If my answer below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It’s mainly due to synchronization issues that need to be kept in kind when using singleton beans in a multithreaded environment. With prototype beans each request for the bean will create a new instance of the bean and thus you don’t need to care about synchronizing access to the bean’s state across threads. But you need to be very careful when mixing prototype and singleton beans as prototype beans will be wired into a singleton bean only once. That is it effectively becomes singleton within this bean...

If you really need to use prototype beans in singleton beans you should [use the `@Lookup` method annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lookup).

Most times you will not encounter the need to use stateful beans as the state is provided by a separate persistence layer or directly by the caller itself.

One example of singleton beans that have a state are caches. By using dedicated cache libraries such as infinispan, guava, hazlecast, ... you don’t need to care much about synchronization here, as this aspect is handled by those libraries for you.

Given your banking example you probably don’t want to store transaction details in an empheral storage such as the Java heap. If your application crashes for some reason all this information will unrecoverably be lost. This information needs to be stored in a  persistent storage such as a database.

Comment: That's right, but in case there is bean A that is singleton; within bean A is a property of type bean B(this is prototype); in this case, in case of bean B, is still only one instance per spring container, beacuse the parent class is singleton.

Comment: where did you found this: `With prototype beans each thread will get a new instance of the bean`? in the spring doc is written `results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made`. With this I understand every thime is reffered in another bean, for instance.

Comment: @LinuRadu, yes `thread` is not the best wording here, it should be request. I'll re-phrase this. In your example above, if you have a third bean `C` with a property of type `B`, there will be a second instance of `B`.

Comment: Right that as you specified, will be created another instance of type B, but regarding `you don’t need to care about synchronizing access to the bean’s state across threads` why do you say that the synchronization issue is resolved? Probably in case you have all the tree-beans prototype(both @RestController and @Service).

Comment: Exactly. The take-away should be "don't use prototype beans"